# How to avoid duplicate sass imports(using @use) on Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, sass, sass-loader

My sass modules can import each other like below.

```
// LinearLayout.scss
@mixin LinearLayout { ... }
linear-layout { @include LinearLayout; }

// ScrollView.scss
@use "LinearLayout" as *;
@mixin ScrollView {
    @include LinearLayout;
    ...
}
scroll-view { @include ScrollView; }
```

And because **each** sass module ends up in the bundled css file by being imported in scripts, the bundled css file contains duplicate css selectors.

How can I remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Webpack 5: [css-minimizer-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin)
- Webpack under 5: [optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin)

### Common requirement under both Webpack versions

- [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-css-extract-plugin)

I haven't dug about this, but it seems both plugins work in a specific webpack bundling lifecycle which is made by `mini-css-extract-plugin`. So you can't use [style-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader), and the thing that was done by it can be done by [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).

The below is how your `webpack.config.ts` should be like. Note that you set `optimization.minimize` as true to make it run also in development.

```
import type Webpack from "webpack";
import HtmlBundler from "html-webpack-plugin";
import CssExtractor from "mini-css-extract-plugin";

// webpack@5
import CssMinimizer from "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin";
// under webpack@5
import CssMinimizer from "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin";

const config: Webpack.Configuration = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new HtmlBundler({
            template: "yourHtmlTemplate.html"
        });
        new CssExtractor({
            filename: "outputCssFilename.css",
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
                use: [
                    CssExtractor.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "resolve-url-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true, // set true to run minimizers also in development
        minimizer: [
            new CssMinimizer(),
        ],
    },
};

export default config;
```

Comment: My favorite part of the sass documentation is:

"@use only ever loads each file once. This ensures you don’t end up accidentally duplicating your dependencies’ CSS many times over."

Which is clearly not even close to true.